# Getting undefined from lodash.find method for an item in a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I am trying to find an item from an array based collection of objects **`values`** using `lodash.find` method but the returned value I get is 'undefined'. Below is the code I am using in **`typescript`**:

```
this.toFilterId = 2;
this.values = [];

//valueModel is a class with properties - id, code and description and I cant change its definition
export class valueModel {
constructor(
  public id: number,
  public code: string,
  public description: string
  ) { }
}

this.values.push(new valueModel(-1, 'TestAll', 'TestAllDesc'));
this.values.push(new valueModel(1, 'Test1', 'Test1Desc'));
this.values.push(new valueModel(2, 'Test2', 'Test2Desc'));
this.values.push(new valueModel(3, 'Test3', 'Test3Desc'));

const selectedValue = lodash.find(this.values, (filterItem: valueModel) => {
          return filterItem.id === this.toFilterId;
      });

//below console prints undefined instead of the valueModel object with id of 2
console.log('selectedValue:', selectedValue);
```

I am not sure why above console log for **`selectedValue`** var is printing 'undefined'. I have referred to lodash docs and other similar questions on `SO` for `lodash.find()` method but it doesnt return correct value.

Can someone please help in figuring out where I am wrong in using `lodash.find()` method?

Comment: I don't think callback function parameter is correct (filterItem:valueModel)

Comment: Show your `valueModel` declaration.

Comment: @alexmac I have added the definition of `valueModel` class..

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine except for the `:valueModel` in the callback.

Remove that unless you are using flow or TypeScript (which hasn't been indicated in the question).

**EDIT** Updated question mentions this is typescript. Regardless, your solution works:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxZPEb?editors=0011

The only exception or variance here is:

a) Your implementation of the valueModel. Double and triple check you can access the id via model.id.

b) You're not correctly importing lodash - console.log(lodash) to double check it is not undefined.

Comment: Yes, I am using typescript in the code..I have added the tag, even if I remove `valueModel` in callback or use `any`, it doesnt work..

Comment: Do I need to cast the `filterItem` object to `valueModel` as not sure about it? `lodash` though is correctly imported..

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to cast. Within your find callback, before the return, `console.log(filterItem.id)`

Comment: Yes, `console.log(filterItem.id)` is returning 2

Comment: Can you do console.log(typeof filterItem.id) and console.log(typeof this.toFilterId)

Comment: both print `number` and I noticed - `lodash.find()` iterates only once for `id: -1`
 and returns undefined

Comment: It makes me think you are using the native find instead of the lodash version or something.....

Comment: sorry, my bad, there is some object reference issue due to which the array collection gets changed. The code is fine as u said earlier in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in the callback function references Window. Try this one:

```
const selectedValue = lodash.find(this.values, ((filterItem: valueModel) => {
    return filterItem.id === this.toFilterId;
}).bind(this));
```

or

```
const self = this;
const selectedValue = lodash.find(this.values, (filterItem: valueModel) => {
    return filterItem.id === self.toFilterId;
});
```

Apparently, there is a difference in how `this` is handled in lambdas by TypeScript and JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure? The `=>` should remove any need for binding or self/this/that

Comment: In JS - yes. But it is TypeScript, which apparently transpiles it to function in this case ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. I'm sure as I tested it with jsfiddle and TypeScript.

Comment: Maybe TS can be configured to transpile lambdas to ES6 lambdas ?

Comment: Weird - TS for me will automatically create a _this itself so you don't need to worry about it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Athis.a%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.a%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.a%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: You're right, but I trust the compiler on the official TS site more :) Perhaps something is up with the way jsfiddle is compiling....

Comment: It seems TS on fiddle is dramatically behind: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1079